# Merge Into History

Tags: git, merge

I have this:

```
a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h  <--dev branch
    \     \
     x--y--z--q--r      <--feature branch
```

I want to perform a side-by-side diff between `r` and `d`, using a tool like Visual Studio Code or Visual Studio.

To my knowledge, those tools will only give the diff I want in reaction to a merge.  So I would like to do this:

```
a--b--c--d---------M    <--dev branch
    \     \       /
     x--y--z--q--r      <--feature branch
```

Here 'M' is not a commit, it is just an uncommitted merge which allows me to easily perform the side-by-side diff between `r` and `d`.  I'm not deleting `e--f--g--h`, I'm just simply ignoring them temporarily.

What series of git commands should I issue to achieve this?

### Update

Using the answer from torek, I did this:

```
git checkout d    //here 'd' is short-hand for a commit hash
git merge --no-commit feature   //this is the 'feature' branch
```

This caused changes from `r`, and only from `r`, to show up as edits.  I don't understand why the changes from `q` did not also appear.  I then tried this:

```
git checkout d
git merge --no-commit q
```

Now the changes for `q` were evident, as expected.  But I'm still trying to get a diff that shows me all the changes: x,y,z,q,r.  I don't understand how merging a branch (my first example) does not give me *all* the changes from that branch.  This defeats the whole point of branches, yes?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions below describe *how to do a temporary merge* (with or without committing), but see *all* the sections below.  Note: the question and answer have now been edited several times as well.  I am going to try to remark on all the separate issues here.

#### Merging non-head-of-branch commits, such as merging `d` and `r`

You may use `git checkout` to select either `d` or `r` (it does not matter which one if you are not going to commit the result):

```
git checkout <hash-id>
```

This produces a *detached HEAD*, as Git calls it: you are now not on any branch, or equivalently, you are on a temporary branch with the name `HEAD`.

Next, ask Git to merge the other commit, using `--no-commit`:

```
git merge --no-commit <hash-id>
```

This will **find the merge base as usual** (boldface because of the next section), perform the merging action (merge as a verb) as usual, and then stop *even if there are no conflicts*.  Without `--no-commit` it would stop only in the case of conflicts.  The merge result is now in the index, ready to be committed if there are no conflicts, or to be resolved if there are.  (Running `git commit`, once any conflicts are resolved, will commit the index.  Or, of course, you can leave out `--no-commit` to have Git do this automatically.  In all cases, the new commit will be your new, still-detached `HEAD`.  Its first parent will be the commit you checked out, and its second parent will be the commit whose ID you passed to `git merge`.)

To abort the merge, if you did not make one after all, use `git merge --abort`.  To get back on some branch—which will abandon the merge commit if you *did* make one—simply `git checkout` any branch name.  (To move `HEAD` elsewhere, leaving it detached while abandoning the merge commit, simply `git checkout` that hash ID.)

#### Problem #1: the merge base

The *merge base* of `r` and `d` in your original diagram is not the same as the merge base of `r` and `d` in your second (pre-edit) diagram.  Here's the first diagram:

```
a--b--c--d--e--f--g--h  <--dev branch
    \     \
     x--y--z--q--r      <--feature branch
```

Here, if we start at commit `r` and work backwards (as Git does), we follow *both parents* of merge commit `z` to see commits `y` and `d` at the same time.  If we start at commit `d` and work backwards (as Git does), we are at commit `d`.  So the merge base of `r` and `d` is `d` (which means Git will demand `--no-ff` to make an actual merge).  This is probably not what you intended.

Meanwhile, at one point you had this:

```
a--b--c--d---------M    <--dev branch
    \             /
     x--y--z--q--r      <--feature branch
```

This is a *different graph*, in which `z` is not a merge commit.  If we follow `d` and `r` backwards to the first commit that is reachable from both, we arrive at commit `b`.  Hence commit `b` is the merge base of *this* diagram.

#### Problem #2: Merge *doesn't care* about intermediate commits

When we—or Git—look at this graph subset (I have trimmed away parts that "come after" and clearly won't contribute anything):

```
a--b--c--d
    \     \
     x--y--z--q--r
```

for figuring out how to do a merge, we might as well be looking at this graph subset instead:

```
d
 \
--z--q--r
```

That is, none of `a-b-c` and `x-y` matter at all.  Moreover, the `z-q` segment is *only* relevant in that we need it to traverse back from `r` to `d`.  This is because each commit's saved *tree*—the source tree we get by doing `git checkout` of one of these hash IDs—is complete unto itself.  We don't *need* `z` and `q` for their *trees*, only for their links that get us to `d` (which is why we can ignore one of `z`'s backwards links as well).

Let's say, just for illustration, that we (rather painstakingly) copy `a-b-c-d` and `x-y-q-z-r` to new commits, except that while we are doing all this, we don't actually do a merge at all for `z`, giving us this graph:

```
a'-b'-c'-d'
    \
     x'-y'-z'-q'-r'
```

When we make these, we use the *same* snapshots for `a'` as for `a`, for `b'` as for `b`, and so on (by copying all the versions of the files out of the original commits, for instance).  Even `z'` matches `z`, in terms of what you get if you `git checkout` them, it's just that `z'`'s *history* linkage does not show it as a merge.<sup>1</sup>

*Now* if we ask Git to merge `d'` and `r'`, the merge base—the point where the graph pieces first join up again as we move backwards through it—is commit `b'`.  But—**here is the problem that this section is all about**—the *way* Git merges these is to run:

```
git diff <hash of b'> <hash of d'>    # first set of changes
git diff <hash of b'> <hash of r'>    # second set of changes
```

and then combine the two diffs into one big change-set applied to `b'`.

The first diff *ignores the source tree* stored in `a'`, of course, because that's not where we are starting from—but it *also* ignores the one in `c'`, because everything that was changed from `b'` to `c'` is *still in* `d'` unless it had to be backed out of `d'` on purpose, in which case it should not be taken.

Likewise, the second diff *ignores the source trees* stored in `x'`, `y'`, `z'`, and `q'`.  They are irrelevant: whatever is in them is *also* in `r'`, *unless* it was *intentionally removed* from `r'`.

**Or, of course, maybe it was *accidentally* removed from `r'`.**  But how would Git ever know this?  All Git cares about is the final snapshot.  The steps taken in between, to *arrive at* the final snapshot, are not important—not to the VCS, anyway.  (Based on comments, it sounds like something went wrong when someone created `r`, or maybe `z`.  Some people *do* make incorrect merges, so it's easy to believe that someone did `z` wrong.)

There are other version control systems that *do* actually go through each step.  Mercurial, which is otherwise very much like Git, does this,<sup>2</sup> for instance.  But that doesn't help either: if, for whatever reason, `r'` *backs out* some or all of the changes found in `q'`, that tells Mercurial that the *intent* of the merge is to stick with the backing-out, so Mercurial's merged source tree matches Git's.

---

<sup>1</sup>Here `z'` is, in fact, what you would get with `git merge --squash`.  A squash "merge" is not *a* merge (noun), but uses Git's merge machinery *to* merge (verb) the commits.  That's mostly only a good idea if you're about to delete the merged-in branch entirely: you do the merge to [drink up all the tasty goodness of the branch's milkshake](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/i-drink-your-milkshake), and then you toss the empty husk of a branch into the rubbish bin.

<sup>2</sup>Well, sort of.  Mercurial only has to track *directory state* through each commit in the chain of commits leading from the two tips back to the merge base, so as to recover the identities of files.  It *sometimes* has to work with multiple deltas to construct the particular file versions as well, but Mercurial occasionally stores a full copy of the file again, so as to avoid very long delta chains.  This is actually quite analogous to Git's pack-files, which likewise store objects as delta-chains, with a maximum chain depth.

---

#### Sad conclusion: there is no magic bullet

This all brings us to our rather sad conclusion: if someone broke the source tree while constructing a chain of commits, there is no magical fix for this.  It does not matter whether the breakage was during a merge, or doing a regular non-merge commit.  If Joe fixed module `mango.py` and then Bob broke it, it does not matter *how* Bob broke it, you now have a broken mango.  What any good VCS will give you is the ability to *find where it broke*, but that still requires going commit by commit, unless...

#### Happy conclusion: sometimes there *is* a magic bullet

If you have an automated test for breakage, *and* the breakage is persistent (does not come and go from commit to commit), you can use `git bisect` (or in Mercurial, `hg bisect`) to *run* the automated test on a huge swath of commits.  These let you mark one commit as "good" and one as "bad".  They try a commit around halfway between the two.  Whether it's good or bad, that divides the problem/fix boundary into whichever half still has the problem.  By repeatedly dividing in half—bisecting, in other words—your VCS can pinpoint one particular bad commit in O(log<sub>2</sub> *n*) tests, where *n* is the number of commits between good and bad.

There's some overhead in setting these up, of course.  For a small number of small-changeset commits, it's probably easier to just look "by hand".

Comment: My question contained an error, which I have now corrected. The 'd to z' merge lineage should still be present.  That said, following these instructions didn't seem to work.  In my result, `r` had merged into `d` (as intended), but somehow `q,z,y,x` all seemed to be ignored.

Comment: OK: if there is a connection from `z` to `d`, then `d` *is* the merge-base, and therefore there's nothing to merge.  Forcing the merge to happen (with `--no-ff`) will just take everything from `r`: Git compares `d` with itself and finds no changes, then compares `d` with `r`, then takes the union of *all* the (i.e., `r`'s) changes, which produces the tree in `r`. (Well, Git cheats for speed reasons, but that is the effect.) You cannot just pick an arbitrary merge base yourself: you must make new commits `c'`, `d'`, etc and leave out `z` when copying, in order to get a new merge.

Comment: All that said, if you want to merge two specific *files* using a third *file* as its merge base, see `git merge-file`, which does just that. A full merge is basically a series of `git merge-file`s with the base files for each one chosen for you automatically. (Not that this helps if the goal is to trick a diff program into showing something!)

Comment: Since `d` was merged to produce commit `z`, the feature branch "knows" about changes on the dev branch.  The opposite is not true.  The dev branch still knows nothing about x, y, z, q, or r.  So when I merge `r` back into the (detached head) `d`, with --no-commit, I expect changes from x,y,z,q and r to suddenly all be captured as changes which I can diff.  Said again, at no point had changes on the feature branch ever been merged to the dev branch.

Comment: Sure, but that would be a one-pair diff: from `d` to `r`.  The base itself is just `d`. Meanwhile, something else occurred to me on my drive home: your diff viewer is probably really a merge tool in disguise. It "wants" a base version, for which you would probably prefer `b`. But remember that Git deals in *snapshots*. Let me edit in another section...

Comment: Wow.  Your answer is amazing.  Particularly helpful was your distinction between Hg and Git.  So in my case, it sounds like my `r` is somehow "bad" because it does not contain changes in `q`.  Groan.  I wonder if there is a way to replay `q` or, better yet, replay a range of commits, so that the sum of changes is re-created.  I guess that is the "cherry-pick" capability?

Comment: Yes, cherry-picking a range of commits effectively turns each commit in that range into a delta and then applies the delta to make a new commit. More or less equivalent—the "less" part centers around rename detection and handling merge commits—you can also `git format-patch` a range of commits and use `git am` to apply them.